# Trying to insert JQuery to chrome extension gives error: "Could not load javascript 'jquery.js' for content script. Could not load manifest."

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

recently I came across an error during trying to get JQuery to my chrome extension. I wrote following code and then when I try to reload my extension in Chrome browser I get the message:

```
Failed to load extension

Error
Could not load javascript 'jquery.js' for content script.
Could not load manifest.
```

The file of jquery was downloaded from their webpage (compressed production 3.5.1).

I checked several webpages connected to this problem but I couldn't find the solution.

Files in which inserting JQuery matters are below:

manifest.json
https://ideone.com/EGKlfQ

```
"manifest_version": 2,
"name" : "name",
"version": "1.0",
"offline_enabled": true,
"content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": [
    "https://www.zalando-lounge.pl/*"
  ],
  "js": ["jquery.js","content.js"]
}

],
"background" : {
"scripts": ["background.js"]
},
"browser_action":{
"default_icon": "img/icon.png",
"default_popup": "popup.html",
"default_title": "A popup will come here"
},
"permissions": ["tabs","storage"],
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/; object-src 'self'"
```

popup.html

https://ideone.com/exMgYq

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

...other code in this file doesn't matter in this case...

Comment: can you show the folder structure?

Comment: @Noobdev Prolly I saved up wrong file. Uncompressed didn't work. Now it's fine. U helped me. Thanks